# Accessing app wide object on template

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I've got an Ember Object defined which only holds some functions. I would like to access these  functions in my templates but somehow it doesn't work. There is no error given nor any log statements.

```
App.AuthManager = Ember.Object.extend({
    isAuthenicated : function () { 
        return true;
    }
}).create();
```

Now in my template I would like to

```
{{#if App.AuthManager.isAuthenticated}}
    <ul>...</ul>
{{/if}}
```

The markup within the if statement is always printed, doesn't handlebars interpret the object function here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The guide on [Handlebars Basic](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/handlebars-basics/) states that

```
Each template has an associated controller: this is where the template finds the properties that it displays.
```

That means the scope of the template is the controller and only the controller, you cannot access other objects in your application straight from a handlebars template.

I think that what you are trying to achieve can be done using the [register](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_register) and [inject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_inject) functions of the [Ember.Application class](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html).

Once the AuthManager object is injected in controllers, you should be able to access the property isAuthenticated within your template like so:

```
{{#if isAuthenticated }}
  <ul>....</ul>
{{/if}}
```

My source for this answer was from this website: http://madhatted.com/2013/5/26/communication-between-controllers-in-ember-js